# Reemplazar símbolo ":" por tabulador en R Studio

Tags: r

tengo una columna con una serie de datos separados entre sí por ":", pero yo quiero separarlos por columnas, pero no lo consigo.

Es decir, tengo:

```
datos
Juan:29384:Madrid
Alba:394839:Alicante
Elena:102948:Segovia
```

Y quiero que me de: (separado por tabuladores, sustituir : por tabulador)

```
datos
Juan     29384     Madrid
Alba     394839    Alicante
Elena    102948    Segovia
```

El código que tengo es este:

```
library(rJava)
library(xlsxjars)
library(xlsx)
separar <-read.xlsx(file="datos.xlsx", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=T, sep=":", sheetIndex = 1)
```

Cargo estas tres librerías para poder abrir un **xlsx**, y luego interpreto que al poner como separador ":" debería considerarlo como separador, pero no lo hace. Sabéis cómo podría hacerlo?
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: yo no se de R, pero en esta pregunta (ingles) se trata algo parecido -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894677/how-to-replace-specific-characters-of-a-string-with-tab-in-r igual puede aplicarlo a lo que recupera del **xlsx**, igual a alguien que sepa de R puede mirar el link y ayudarlo, Update: parece ser que `gsub`es la clave, le dejo un link -> http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

`read.xlsx` transforma un planilla Excel en un `dataframe`, la columna que tiene múltiples valores no va a dejar de ser una única columna del `dataframe`, si no me equivoco, además el parámetro `sep` no es un parámetro de la función `read.xlsx`. Lo que deberías luego de importar los datos es hacer un split en la columna que tiene los ':' para transformarlo en múltiples columnas, por ejemplo:

```
list <- "id datos
        1 Juan:29384:Madrid
        2 Alba:394839:Alicante
        3 Elena:102948:Segovia"

df = read.table(textConnection(list), header=TRUE) 
within(df, datos<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(datos), ':', fixed=TRUE))))
```

Lo cual te dejaría el `dataframe` como:

```
  id datos.X1 datos.X2 datos.X3
1  1     Juan    29384   Madrid
2  2     Alba   394839 Alicante
3  3    Elena   102948  Segovia
```